# Let $T,U:V\to W$ be linear transformations. Prove that if $W$ is finite-dimensional, then $\text{rank}(T+U)\leq\text{rank}(T) + \text{rank}(U)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, matrix-rank

Let $T,U:V\to W$ be linear transformations.

(a) Prove that $R(T+U)\subseteq R(T) + R(U)$.

(b) Prove that if $W$ is finite-dimensional, then $\text{rank}(T+U)\leq\text{rank}(T) + \text{rank}(U)$.

**MY ATTEMPT**

(a) If $w\in R(T+U)$, there exists $v\in V$ such that $w = (T+U)v = T(v) + U(v)$.

But $T(v)\in R(T)$ and $U(v)\in R(U)$.

Thus $w\in R(T) + R(U)$, from whence we conclude that $R(T+U)\subseteq R(T)+R(U)$.

(b) Since $R(T + U)$ is a linear subspace of $R(T)+R(U)$, we have that
\begin{align*}
\dim R(T+U) & \leq \dim(R(T) + R(U)) = \dim R(T) + \dim R(U) - \dim(R(T)\cap R(U))\\\\
& \leq \dim R(T) + \dim R(U)
\end{align*}

Could someone verify if I am not doing any conceptual mistake?

Comment: That's all correct.

Comment: The equality you use in b) is worth proving. Though you don’t really need it, you can skip to the inequality. The proof of that id easier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$a)$ looks good.

$b)$ follows from $a)$, since $\operatorname{rank}T=\operatorname{dim}R(T)$

(You correctly used the formula for the dimension of the sum of two subspaces.)

Answer (score 1):

Concepts:

a)This shows$$ R(T+U)$$
 is a subspace of $$R(T)+R(U).$$

b) Note $$T+U: V \rightarrow W$$ 
is a linear transformation, 
  $$ rank(T)$$ and $$rank(U) ≤ dim W $$(finite). Hence,$$ rank(T) + rank(U) $$ is finite.

Let's do it,

a) $x',y'$ are in $R(T+U)$
  $ \rightarrow$ there exist $x,y$ in$ V$ such that $(T+U)(x) = x'$, 
$(T+U)(y) = y'$
       $ \rightarrow x'+y'=(T+U)(x)+(T+U)(y) =(T+U)(x+y)= T(x)+U(x) + T(y)+ U(y)
       = T(x+y) + U(x+y) $
       $ x'+y'$ is in $R(T)+R(U)$
       $ x'  \in R(T+U)$ and $c$ is a scalar, then,
      there exist $ x,y \in V $ such that $(T+U)(x) = x'$
      $\rightarrow (T+U)(cx) $ $= c(T+U)(x) = cx' = T(cx)+ U(cx)  $ for some $ x \in V$
      $\rightarrow cx' \in R(T) + R(U)$
      This shows $R(T+U)$ is a subspace of $ R(T)+R(U).$
It looks a little bit more complicated but it's the same.

b) it looks good.